# Original video sharper than editted (PP CS6)

Tags: premiere, cs6

I've notests this for a while now, but it seems Premiere Pro CS6 is making the edited video more soft / less sharp. I'm using a GoPro Hero4 / Session2 in 1080p/60fps and it seems the only way I can get the production video to be as sharp as the original is by encoding it in 4k. If I encode it on 1080p/60fps (same as input) the image gets washed out no matter what encodig settings I use.

I've used FFmpeg for other encoding jobs, and that generates much more sharp video's than PP CS6 does in much smaller formats. So it can't be the encoding.

Could this be some wrong setting? Maybe this is a known "feature" of Premiere? It doesn't matter if I encode the video at 10mbps or 100mbps, the output is just washed out. It's not much, but its enough to get on my nerves.

Comment: You are using a version of Premier that is now 5 releases (6 years) behind and you're not comparing apples to apples if you use a recent copy of FFmpeg to CS6.  You are highly unlikely to get any support from anybody here because nobody is using CS6 anymore.

Comment: CS6 is still widely used as it was the last release that did not fall under the new Adobe Licensing Model. Copies of the Production Premium Bundle of CS6 still fetch $1500+ because of this.

Comment: First, when you create the sequence that you cut on, either use the Match Sequence Settings when dragging one of your clips to a new sequence/timeline, or right click the source file and click Create Sequence from Clip.   Your video shouldn't be softer, especially at 100mbps. What codec are you using for output?

Comment: Martin A, I do setup the video in the same format when I drag the first video. Also all video's are the same format so the settings keep being right. I'm using H.264 as output (profile baseline 5.1, NTSC Square Pixels (1.0), VBR 2 pass)

Comment: Have you retried a 2 pass VBR and ticked 'render at maximum depth'option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a subscription for Premiere CC, and it seems to be much better. So TravisO was right, CS6 is just too old.